# Multiple connection to DbContext in EFCore and .net Core2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext, ef-core-2.0

I have facing a problem to connecting to DBcontext with multiple connection. please help me out from this problem , here is me scenario .

1. I have an Angular5 application and Webapi Controllers. I have 4 databases and Each database has different users .
2. When 4 user are trying to connecting to their database at Same time through Webapi controller , that  time all users are getting data from single database (instead of getting different database ) .
3. When we try to Connecting  one by one then data getting correctly .

Here is my sample code for dynamic connection .

**Context Connectionstring :**

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
         #warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
          optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(LoginController.ConnectionString);

    }
```

Controler API :

```
public IEnumerable<object> Getvendordetails([FromBody] dynamic id)
    {
        if (Request != null)
        {
            LoginController.DynamicDbname = Request.Headers["Connectionstring"];
        }
        ContextEntity obj = new ContextEntity();
    }
```

Here  **LoginController.DynamicDbname** is  Static variable .

**EDIT CODE :**

Controller :

```
    namespace AngularDotnetCore.Controllers
   {
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;
       private ContextEntity db;
      public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext)
    {

        this.httpContext = _httpContext;
        db = new ContextEntity(httpContext);

    }
    [HttpPost("GetVendors")]
    public IEnumerable<object> Getvendordetails([FromBody] dynamic id)
    {
        //string DynamicConnection = Request.Headers["Connection"];
        db = new ContextEntity(httpContext);
        return db.Vendors;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetItems")]
    public IEnumerable<object> GetItems()
    {
        //string DynamicConnection = Request.Headers["Connection"];
        db = new ContextEntity(httpContext);
        return db.Items;
    }

}
```

}

**DBContext :**

```
   private readonly HttpContext httpContext;
  public ContextEntity(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    : base()
    {
        httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }
     protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
       var connection = httpContext.Request.Headers["Connection"];
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);

   }
```

I have pass httpcontext parameter to Dbcontext base class for each API Request.

Please help me on this problem , if my code is wrong please suggest me in good way.

Thanks
Victor.A

Comment: Why in the world are you injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` into your *controller*? The controller already has access to `HttpContext` directly.

Answer (score 1):

If LoginController.DynamicDbName is a static variable, It is shared between all your requests. It means Your API is overrading this value on each request and all users are using the last one to create dbconnection. Make it non static and create new instance of your login contoller  for each request and inject It to all related services like DbContext. Then your problem will disappear.

If you are using migrations from command line, you might need to upgrade EF Core version to 2.1 (or 2.2, I can't remeber) because 2.0 has some problem with injecting  not-standard classes/interfaces to your Context

Comment: Michał Jarzyna , Thank you for your reply ...  If create a new instance of login controller , then how can i pass Connection variable  to OnConfiguring Method to update the connection .... Give me some idea please....

Comment: Hence I am writing from the phone, i can't pass the code, but you need to inject in your Context constructor the controller like 'MyContext(..., LoginContoller contoller){ _loginContoller = contoller;}' and in OnConfiguring use _loginContoller.DynamicDbName

Comment: And if evetything will work, think about moving variable from LoginController to smaller class like ConnectionIdentity or ConnectionConfiguration, Just for making code cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

For accessing http header from `DbContext`, you could try `IHttpContextAccessor`, there is no need to refer `LoginContoller`.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connection = httpContext.Request.Headers["Connectionstring"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
    }       
}
```

**Edit** It seems you initlize the `ContextEntity` in the controller instead of using DI, if so, try passing the connectionstring directly instead of `IHttpContextAccessor`.

```
namespace AngularDotnetCore.Controllers
   {
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{      
   private ContextEntity db;
  public HomeController()
{

    var connection = Request.Headers["Connection"];
    db = new ContextEntity(connection);

}
  }
```

`DbContext`

```
private readonly string _connection;
  public ContextEntity(string connection)
: base()
{
    _connection = connection;
}
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
  optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connection);

    }
```

Comment: Hello Tao Zhou, i tried this , but httpContext always getting null, should i add this in services ? or is there any different way to get this ...   Thanks

Comment: @VictorAthoti. try `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in `startup.cs`. If not work, share us a demo to reproduce your issue. How did you use the `DbContext`? Reference it in controller or anywhere?

Comment: I have updated my code  please check it . Now i can able to use httpcontext in Dbcontext base constructor .   I have a Question " If My clients hitting the API at the same time , Will it work for different databases OR will it messing up data base ... Please suggest me .... --Thanks.

Comment: This is wrong. Do not inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your context. If you need access to that, you can get it via the internal service provider.

Comment: @VictorAthoti. For `Dbcontext`, it is scoped and will be created for every request. Just share us the test result.

Comment: Exactly what I said. Don't inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into the context.

Comment: @Tao Zhou, I got an error some time  " System.InvalidOperationException: 'An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'
"  any idea why im getting this error .

Comment: @VictorAthoti. did you passing `IHttpContextAccessor ` or `connection`?

Comment: @Tao Zhou, I passed IHttpContextAccessor  in my Interface not in controller .... public class BizRepository : IBizRepository
    {
         public BizRepository(IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext)
        {
            httpContext = _httpContext;
            db = new BiztechnologiesContext(httpContext);
        }

Comment: @VictorAthoti. Change it passing `Request.Headers["Connection"]` to `BiztechnologiesContext` instead of `httpContext`

Comment: @Tao Zhou, Sorry i did not get you what you saying , Should i pass BiztechnologiesContext to Dbcontext constructor ...?  at present my context like this ....  public BiztechnologiesContext(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base()
        {
           
            httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
           
        }

Comment: Here is the OnConfiguring ... protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
          var connection = httpContext.Request.Headers["connection"];
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
            }
        }

Comment: @VictorAthoti. check my update answer. Change `BiztechnologiesContext(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) ` to `BiztechnologiesContext(string connection)`