# Dynamically change DBContext connection string in Asp.Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to write code for dynamically changing connection string based on parameter.

In my scenario, I have multiple DBconexts and need to get a connection string for Type1 context from global context tables based on the parameter(integer).

Comment: How will you set the value for `Id` dynamically? Try to refer [Multiple connection to DbContext in EFCore and .net Core2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019024/multiple-connection-to-dbcontext-in-efcore-and-net-core2-0/53038342#53038342)

Comment: Thanks for reply Tao. I am planning to get Id from httpRequest. I checked code from the provided link, It was using Dbcontext onconfiguring. I want to avoid this for clean code and i want to use DI after setting connection string in a startup class.   Check this link https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9616 you can add change connection string i startup class based on the above link if you use Core 2.0 or greater